Listings rendering horizontal lines randomly?
I want to display SQL queries but I keep having problems with the listings package. At one point I reduced my defined parameters just to styling and still got some horizontal lines but at random places. It seems like some caching property perhaps? Am I missing something here?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}

% Define colors
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{RGB}{207,142,109}   
\definecolor{stringcolor}{RGB}{105,170,114}   
\definecolor{commentcolor}{RGB}{122,126,133}   
\definecolor{bgcolor}{RGB}{30,31,34}         
\definecolor{numbercolor}{RGB}{41,172,184}  
\definecolor{defaultcolor}{RGB}{199,125,187} 
\definecolor{operatorcolor}{RGB}{188,190,196}  
\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{75,80,89}

% Define SQL style
\lstdefinestyle{sql}{
    language=SQL,
    backgroundcolor=\color{bgcolor},   
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{defaultcolor}, 
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\small\bfseries\color{keywordcolor}, 
    commentstyle=\color{commentcolor}\itshape,  
    stringstyle=\color{stringcolor},   
    numbers=left,                      
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{rulecolor}, 
    stepnumber=1,                      
    numbersep=10pt,                     
    showstringspaces=false,            
    tabsize=4,                         
    breaklines=true,                   
    breakatwhitespace=false,           
    frame=tb,                      
    framesep=8pt,                     
    framerule=0.5pt,
    rulecolor=\color{rulecolor},       
    captionpos=b,                     
    keepspaces=true,                  
    xleftmargin=20pt,                 
    framexleftmargin=20pt,
    morekeywords={SELECT, FROM, WHERE, AND, OR, NOT, IN, BETWEEN, LIKE, JOIN, INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL, ON, GROUP, BY, ORDER, LIMIT, OFFSET, HAVING, DISTINCT, UNION, EXCEPT, INSERT, INTO, VALUES, UPDATE, SET, DELETE, CREATE, TABLE, ALTER, DROP, INDEX, VIEW, PROCEDURE, FUNCTION, TRIGGER, CASCADE, PRIMARY, FOREIGN, KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT, DEFAULT, AS, NULL, IS},
    literate=
        {0}{{{\color{numbercolor}0}}}{1}
        {1}{{{\color{numbercolor}1}}}{1}
        {2}{{{\color{numbercolor}2}}}{1}
        {3}{{{\color{numbercolor}3}}}{1}
        {4}{{{\color{numbercolor}4}}}{1}
        {5}{{{\color{numbercolor}5}}}{1}
        {6}{{{\color{numbercolor}6}}}{1}
        {7}{{{\color{numbercolor}7}}}{1}
        {8}{{{\color{numbercolor}8}}}{1}
        {9}{{{\color{numbercolor}9}}}{1}
        {=}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{=}}}{1}     
        {<}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{<}}}{1}
        {>}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{>}}}{1}
        {<=}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{<=}}}{2}
        {>=}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{>=}}}{2}
        {<>}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{<>}}}{2}
        {!=}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{!=}}}{2}
        {+}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{+}}}{1}      
        {-}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{-}}}{1}      
        {*}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{*}}}{1}    
        {/}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{/}}}{1}    
        {.}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{.}}}{1}      
        {,}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{,}}}{1}
        {[}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{(}}}{1}
        {]}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{)}}}{1}
        {;}{{\textcolor{operatorcolor}{;}}}{1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
\lstset{style=sql}
\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT id 
FROM teaches 
WHERE semester = 'Fall' 
  AND id NOT IN [
    SELECT id 
    FROM teaches 
    WHERE semester = 'Spring' 
      AND YEAR = 2010
  ]
EXCEPT
SELECT id 
FROM teaches 
WHERE YEAR = 2009;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\caption{SQL query using a nested subquery and EXCEPT}
\label{fig:sql_where_clause}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


I don't see it, so this might be browser-dependent. What browser are you using? Do you see it in other browsers?

I have tried Overleaf under Firefox and Texifier with pdfLaTeX. The lines vary in position from environment to environment, but no clean result.

It's not even visible in Adobe Reader @ 1200% zoom, so this is definitely browser-related/-dependent, and has nothing to do with (La)TeX. Try opening up the PDF in an independent (dedicated) viewer, not in Overleaf or TeXifier.

The problem persists with mac's PDF viewer. I tried using TexpadTex and pdfLaTeX in a new document and only in the latter the problem appears after compiling. What are you using to compile?

pdflatex on Windows (up-to-date TL 2024).

I generated the pdf on a mac (thanks OP for a min working example). I don't see the lines in Acrobat, but I do see them in Skim and Preview, in fact lines in different places depending on how much I zoom. Pretty frustrating for you. My solution, which probably won't meet your needs: remove the line backgroundcolor=\color{bgcolor}, so the backgound is white, then it's fine in all viewers.

It might be better to join listings and tcolorbox and then let tcolorbox control the background. The tcolorbox` manual has more about it.

I haven't really got around in Tex, so for me it is kinda magic that switching the version works. I think I will go with compiling manually at the end when my thesis is done using TexpadTex and until then stick with pdfLatex. As this is just a minor inconvenience.

Switching the color schema from dark mode to normal mode (i.e., no background color, which would fix the issue of the horizontal lines) may also be an option - it is of course a matter of preference but I find light styles usually easier to read in the context of a pdf document.
